# Class init in Python with custom list of parameters, set default if parameters is not explicitly passed

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, parameter-passing

I want to define in Python 3.9 a class which gets as a parameter a dictionary or a list of arguments and sets the class attributes in the following matter:

1. If the key name is passed in the argument it uses it to set the corresponding class attribute.
2. If the key name is not passed, it sets the class attribute with a default value.

One way to do this is:

```
class example():
   def __init__(self, x=None, y=None):
       if x is None:
          self.x = "default_x"
       else:
          self.x = x
       if y is None:
          self.y = "default_y"
       else:
          self.y = y
```

or shortly (thank to matszwecja):

```
class example():
   def __init__(self, x="default_x", y="default_y"):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do so without hard-coding `if` to each parameter? I want some flexibility so that if I add another attribute in the future, I won't be needed to hard-code another if for it.

I want to declare a class with

```
class example():
   def __init__(kwargs):
     ?
```

Such as if I pass `example(y="some", z=1, w=2)` it will generate

```
self.x = "default_x"
self.y = "some"
self.z = 1
self.w = 2
```

Comment: `x = 'default_x'` instead of `x=None`? That's literally what default is for.

Comment: Yes, but I want that I can pass the argument in a dynamic way, so I won't need to specify the entire list of arguments in the header.

Comment: I don't understand how that changes anything. You're already doing the exact same thing, just setting it to `None` for some reason instead of the actual default value you want.

Comment: This is how I do it now. Is there an automated way to generate the list of `self.x` from the arguments?

Comment: Something like this? https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-dataclass/

Comment: Judging by your latest edit, it looks like you might want to use something like a dict, not instance attributes.

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit". I would argue that @matswecja's suggestion *is* the Pythonic solution, and while `if` statements are necessary when you need to use a sentinel like `None` in place of a mutable default value.

Comment: You might consider using a dataclass to have such an `__init__` method generated *for* you.

Comment: DRY is often taken too literally. Just because (you think) you are repeating yourself, doesn't mean you are repeating yourself *unnecessarily*. Plus, some repetition is *good* for readable code; you don't want automate a bunch of boilerplate to the point where a reader has to execute the code in their mind to figure out what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
class example():
    def __init__(self, x="default_x", y="default_y"):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a dataclass to generate the boilerplatey `__init__` method for you.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Example:
    x: str = "default_x"
    y: str = "default_y"
```

If you need to provide a mutable default (say, a new empty list if no explicit list is provided), you can use `dataclasses.field` to explicitly create a field with a default factory; the `dataclass` decorator uses the `Field` object to generate the necessary code for the instance attribute.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Example:
    x: str = "default_x"
    # Bad!
    # y: list[str] = []
    y: list[str] = field(default_factory=list)  # Good
```